# Paypal: how to store credit card and take automatic payments

Tags: paypal

With paypal is possible to store the credit card of the customer (that has put during the registratin process) and take an automatic payment (so not initiated by the user himself)?

Which paypal payment solution should i use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, so I will give you a very broad answer.  There are a number of different ways to do that depending on your goal.

The following APIs would give you what you're asking for in various ways.

- [Express Checkout / Payments Pro Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)
- [Express Checkout / Payments Pro Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/)
- [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#adaptive), specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).